# MongoDB router server priority

Tags: java, mongodb, routes

My application creates a MongoClient object with some configuration to create a connection to two separate servers, which are running `mongos` (MongoDB router) to a cluster of servers. My question is that how to prioritize the connection of these routers? I'd like to connect `routerA`, and connect to `routerB` only if the `routerA` is inaccessible. The property `Read Preference` is only for replicate servers, not for routers, so using that would be no help I thought. Should I arrange this priority structure manually, or is there some configuration that I can use?

An image to clarify for those who hates to read long paragraphs;
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to configure this, thus created two connections to both `RouterA` and `RouterB`, manually controlling the traffic of my app, pinging and accessing through A, and only in case of failure of A, access through B.